# Is MotionBuilder compatible with Blender?

Tags: modeling, motion-capture

I want to animate a face, a Motion Capture animation. I learned that MotionBuilder is great for doing that. Does MotionBuilder work with Blender?

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting to bring mocap files from MB to Blender, or from Blender to MB and back to Blender?

Comment: Thanks Todd for your note. I want to create Facial Motion Capture. Blender doesn't seem to do that. I noticed that MotionBuilder does that. So I thought perhaps I can create a facial mocap character and then mix it with a body created in blender. Maybe that is not the right way to do it. I bought Perception Neuron ( http://kck.st/1uxn8UG ) that can easily create Motion Capture for body but not for face. So how can I use Blender and MotionBuilder to create Facial MoCap? ... Thanks Todd.

Comment: I guess it depends on how MB exports the facial mocap data. If it exports some type of armature, perhaps you can parent it to your face mesh in Blender.

Answer (score 1):

You can export animations from Motion Builder in FBX or BVH formats, which Blender can import as an animated armature.